# user.roles.map throws cannot read map of undefined Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make roles by reaction in my bot, but it doesn't send the roles that the user has
Always gives error on 'map'

Code in index.js:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if(user.bot) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
    if(reaction.message.id === '881057147692138546'){
    if(reaction.emoji.name === 'r_check_pde') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('879244179945963571')
        }
    }
    if(reaction.message.id === '881057147692138546'){
    if(reaction.emoji.name === 'r_check_pde') {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove('879957726128648263')
            user.send(
              new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setDescription("Registrado")
              .addField('Roles:', user.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true)
              )
        }
    }
})
```

Error message:

> cannot ready property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User) class has no `roles` property. This only exists on [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)s. You will have to change it to this:

```js
const member = await reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user.id)
//...
addField('Roles:', member.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true) //notice you also have to access the 'cache' property
```